# Is there a topological proof that additon and multiplication are continous functions from $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R $ into $\mathbb R $?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Is there a topological proof that additon and multiplication are continous functions from $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R $ into $\mathbb R $? That is, can we prove continuity using the topological description of a continuous function?

I know that one can make a "$\epsilon $- $\delta $ argument, but this proof isn't so "elegant", and of course these two definitions are equivalent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any reason you should be able to avoid writing the letter $\varepsilon$. After all, open in $\Bbb R^2$ means that for every point in the open set, there's an $\varepsilon$-ball around it also contained within it...

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. For me the definition of continuous function _is_ topological, and proving something is continuous will ultimately have to use the definition somewhere. So I would say _every_ proof meets your criteria.

Comment: Marc, what I meant was that if one could prove directly that for anny open set in $\mathbb R $ the preimage is open in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R $.

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be the addition. It's easy to see that $\alpha^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is open for every $c$, so addition is upper semicontinuous. And symmetrically, you see that $\alpha^{-1}((c,+\infty))$ is open, so $\alpha$ is lower semicontinuous. Hence $\alpha$ is continuous. But, really, that's not better than the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$.

Given an open set $O\subset\mathbb{R}$, let $(a,b) \in f^{-1} (O)$. Then $a+b \in O$, since $O$ is open, there exists a ball centered at $a+b$ with radius $\epsilon$ such that 
$$B_{a+b}(\epsilon) \subset O.$$
By construction 
$$(a,b) \in B_a\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \times B_b\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \subset f^{-1}(B_{a+b}(\epsilon)) \subset f^{-1} (O),$$
thus $f^{-1} (O)$ is open.

**Edit:** the inclusion $B_a\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \times B_b\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \subset f^{-1}(B_{a+b}(\epsilon))$ is clear, but not trivial, you might want to write a short argument for this on a test.

Comment: Of course this is just a rephrasement of the usual $\epsilon$-proof. Nothing wrong about that, but it supports the other comments that Alexander's question doesn't make much sense. Somewhere the definition of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has to enter.

Comment: Of course the easiest way is to work with a norm on $\mathbb{R}$. For a normed linear space $X$, together with the strong topology $\mathcal{T}$ induced by the norm would make $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological vector space which means that $+, \times$ are continuous from $X\times X\rightarrow X$. It just follows from the subadditivity and homogeneity of the norm. But  I don't look at Alexander's question as a bad question.

Comment: @Martin where in the usual $\epsilon $-proof does the definition of the topology on $R $ enter?

Comment: $B_a\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \times B_b\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)$ is your "$\delta$ radius ball" in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Another remark, $(X,\mathcal{T})$ forms a topological vector space for topologies that are weaker than the strong topology induced by the norm. In that case, the standard $\epsilon-\delta$ definition will not work.